# IBM MFP8 JavaScript Adapter connection timeout

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am working with IBM MFP 8 JavaScript Adapters. As per the blogs or documentation below the request from Cordova Application.

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
    "adapters/LoginAdapter/validateLogin", 
    WLResourceRequest.POST 
);
resourceRequest.sendFormParameters(params).then(
    ( response ) => {
        resolve( response );
    }, ( error ) => {
        reject( error );
    } 
);
```

My problem here is, if I call the above method I get Connection Timeout. But if I pass the full url as below, it works.

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest( 
    'http://xxx.xx.xx:9080/mfp/api' + "adapters/LoginAdapter/validateLogin", 
    WLResourceRequest.POST 
);

resourceRequest.sendFormParameters(params).then(
    ( response ) => {
        resolve( response );
    }, ( error ) => {
        reject( error );
    } 
);
```

Can anyone please confirm me if I have to pass the full URL for Adapter connection.

Thanks in advance.

Update :

When I try connecting to Adapters from IBM Mobile Simulator, I get the below error and connection is not established.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined
at __WLDAO.getItem (ibmmfpf-preview.js:8285)
at getItemFromMap (ibmmfpf-preview.js:4363)
at Object.__getCachedScopeByResource (ibmmfpf-preview.js:4410)
at __send (ibmmfpf-preview.js:6776)
at sendRequestAsync (ibmmfpf-preview.js:6660)
at WL.ResourceRequest.sendFormParameters (ibmmfpf-preview.js:6577)
at HomePage.webpackJsonp.191.HomePage.login (home.ts:21)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (HomePage.html:18)
at handleEvent (core.es5.js:11914)
at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13206)
bound @ ibmmfpf-preview.js:1334
View_HomePage_0 @ HomePage.html:18
proxyClass @ compiler.es5.js:14091
DebugContext_.logError @ core.es5.js:13146
bound @ ibmmfpf-preview.js:1334
ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.es5.js:1144
IonicErrorHandler.handleError @ ionic-error-handler.js:63
(anonymous) @ core.es5.js:9410
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.es5.js:2687
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
onInvokeTask @ core.es5.js:4140
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
r.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
invoke @ polyfills.js:3
ibmmfpf-preview.js:1334 ERROR CONTEXT
```

Comment: check your ip adress and port number in  mfpclient.properties file.

Comment: I verified them, they are correct.

Comment: http://xxx.xx.xx:9080 Is this pointing to your local server or remote server ?

Comment: It is my local server. My Mobile and server are in same LAN. I am able to access the MFP console in the mobile browser

Comment: Did you check in emulator or in preview ?

Comment: No, I didn't. I will try that now.

Comment: It is not connecting to MFP server, I am getting some error saying GetItem not found.

Comment: can you update question with updated error

Comment: Please check your adapter and try to get response using swegger.

Comment: Relative URL is sufficient to invoke an MFP adapter. If you are invoking a non-MFP endpoint, you can provide the complete URL.

Comment: I am invoking MFP adapter only. Its not working without full path. I observed the same in another machine also.